# How to enable format in routes with ServiceStack in tandem with custom routes?

Tags: rest, servicestack

I have some ServiceStack services that are working well and matching the Route attributes; however, the Route attributes don't appear to work in tandem with the "automatic routing".

I would like to define routes (eg: /things/{id}) and also have the option of format in the url.  Adding the format as a parameter currently works.

```
[Route("/things")]
[Route("/things/{id}")]
public class Things
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

/api/things
/api/things/{1} (return default format)
/api/json/things
/api/json/things/{1}
/api/xml/things
/api/xml/things/{1}
```

According to the ServiceStack wiki, the format in the URL should "just work".  Any suggestions on how to enable it in the apphost config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the wiki page on [Routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing) for documentation on how Routing works, e.g. if you wanted to use pre-defined routes the correct urls would be:

```
/api/json/reply/Things
/api/json/reply/things?Id=1
/api/xml/reply/Things
/api/xml/reply/things?Id=1
```

Note: the pre-defined **only** uses the **name of the Request DTO**, i.e. it does not use all your custom routes.

The [Content Negotiation section on Routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#content-negotiation) wiki shows the different ways to request different Content-Types. In ServiceStack (v3.9.54+) you can now use a format **.ext** e.g:

```
/api/things.json
/api/things/1.json
/api/things.xml
/api/things/1.xml
```

Which is an alternative to using the **?format=ext** parameter:

```
/api/things?format=json
/api/things/1?format=json
/api/things?format=xml
/api/things/1?format=xml
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I missed the second section of the Content Negotiation section of the wiki that shows that .ext is supported (similar to mvc).  2 small follow-up questions if I may: (1) how to move the ext position (ie: /api.ext/).  not a deal-breaker, but possible in mvc routing.  (2) some IDs are strings, and sometimes with a dot (bob.dole).  Sending bob.dole.json worked like a charm.  How?

Comment: 1) It only works at the end of the pathInfo, not in the middle. 2) It only looks at the end extension and will only have an effect if the extension is a built-in or user-registered Content-Type.

Comment: Thank you for prompt follow-up.